# Why does value_count method in Pandas returns a zero count?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that stores the college a high school student is enrolled in.

```
 School     Student_id 
   A             111
   A             112
   B             223
```

I am using the value_counts() function to see the list of unique colleges and the number of students enrolled in each college. However, the list contains quite a few colleges with 0 counts. Why is that possible? Isn't the whole value count concept is built around the fact a school has to appear in the dataset to be counted? What am I missing here?

The dtype is string.

Code:

```
ncee_sample_2005.clg.nunique() # Numer of unique colleges
49
ncee_sample_2005.clg.value_counts() # Visually check the college list
哈尔滨工业大学           9
吉林大学                 7
哈尔滨工程大学           7
浙江大学城市学院          0
浙江大学                 0
```

Comment: What is `df.dtypes` ?

Comment: See update......

Comment: And for those who downvote, explain.

Comment: Can you add the snippet after applying value counts and how you are applying value counts

Comment: @YanSong - I think `str` dtype not exist, only `object`. But if not category dtype like in my answer, then it is really interesting. Is possible explain more? Because if some value is not in column is not possible count it (with exception categorical).

Comment: @YanSong - Or is possible add your code for count it?

Comment: @jezrael I will add code snippets and screen shot shortly.

Comment: @YanSong - Super, I am really curious.

Comment: @jezrael Please see updates. Some characters are in Chinese.

Comment: @Yan Song - Is possible upload file csv with data to dropbox, gdocs? Or if possible save your dataframe to pickle file?

Answer (score 3):

If column is categorical, is it possible, because for missing categories are added `0` - check [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#operations):

```
print (df['Student_id'].dtype)
category

print (df['Student_id'])
0    111
1    112
2    223
Name: Student_id, dtype: category
Categories (4, int64): [111, 112, 223, 100]

s = df['Student_id'].value_counts()
print (s)
223    1
112    1
111    1
100    0
Name: Student_id, dtype: int64
```